# My basic redux store does not console.log state changes

Tags: redux

I am currently working on NetNinja's redux playlist. Unfortunately, I've hit an issue that I'm struggling to overcome. I started working on dispatching multiple actions to my reducer, and now I can no longer get my store.subscribe method to execute a console.log of updated state. I've spent about 40 minutes trying to sole the issue, and any help would be very appreciated.

Here is a direct link to the CodePen I am working on: https://codepen.io/davidreke/pen/MWKWYdd

If you prefer, here is my code in Stack Overflow

```js
const {
  createStore
} = Redux;

console.log('the basics work')

const initState = {
  todos: [],
  posts: []
}
// 2. add a spread operator to include all the state in a reducer
function myReducer(state = initState, action) {
  if (action.type == 'ADD_TODO') {
    return {
      ...state,
      todos: [...state.todos, action.todo]
    }

    if (action.type == 'ADD_POST') {
      return {
        ...state,
        posts: [...state.posts, action.post]
      }
    }
  }

  const store = createStore(myReducer)

  // 1. add a subscription to the store and then preview it in the console.log

  store.subscribe(() => {
    console.log('state updated');
    console.log(store.getState())
  })


  store.dispatch({
    type: 'ADD_TODO',
    todo: 'sleep some more'
  })

  store.dispatch({
    type: 'ADD_TODO',
    todo: 'prepare node.js'
  })


  store.dispatch({
    type: 'ADD_POST',
    post: 'Hello world!'
  })
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/redux/4.0.5/redux.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

I was missing a curly bracket in my reducer function that broke the code.

```
function myreducer(state = initState, action){
  if (action.type =='ADD_TODO') {
    return {
      ...state,
      todos: [...state.todos, action.todo]
    } 
  }

  if (action.type =='ADD_POST') {
    return {
      ...state,
      posts: [...state.posts, action.post]
    }
  }
}
```